# Setting ngStorage to variable value (string)

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, local-storage

I am trying to abstract a `factory` which retrieves data from Parse.com.

Ideally I would like to use this code to pass in the name of the class (string variable) I am querying and then set the returned values to `$localStorage` (from [here](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)) using the same key as the variable.

For example:

```
.factory('userDataFactory', function(ParseFactory, $localStorage, errorFactory, _) {
    var userQuery = {
        'userId': Parse.User.current().id
    };
    return {

        getData: function(targetClass) {
            ParseFactory.provider(targetClass, userQuery).getAll().success(function(data) {
                var flattened = _.extend.apply(_, data.results);

                    // insert variable name here
                    $localStorage.targetClass = flattened;


                }
            }).error(function(response) {
                return errorFactory.checkError(response);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

You will note that I am calling other factories from this `.factory` would this be considered 'bad form'?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that at all.  Invoking other services from a service is common in Angular (think of when you use $http or another Angular built-in service).  The only issue I see is you are using the Parse object without injecting it as a dependency.  If that is also an Angular service, just inject it like you have the ParseFactory.

Comment: Hi Derek, please can you help me with the setting of the local storage according to the value of the variable that I am inputting?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

`$localStorage[targetClass] = flattened;`

using square brackets rather than `.`

Comment: if I put $sessionStorage['mysession'] works perfect but in my chrome developer panel it shows something like: 'ngStorage-mysession'  by any chance do you know how can I avoid the default name and just put 'mysession'?

Comment: Not something I've tried to be honest. Likely to need to look under the hood in the ngStorage library.